# Protect /analytics on Nginx with basic authentication, but allow access to .php and .js files?

Tags: nginx, php, http-basic-authentication, piwik

Hope this is the right place to ask. I have Piwik setup and running on a Nginx webserver that I protected with HTTP basic authentication, as seen below.

```
location /analytics {
    alias /var/www/piwik/;
    auth_basic "Restricted";
    auth_basic_user_file /etc/nginx/pass;
    try_files $uri $uri/ /index.php;
}

location ~ ^/analytics(.+\.php)$ {
    alias /var/www/piwik$1;
    fastcgi_split_path_info ^(.+\.php)(/.+)$;
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root$fastcgi_script_name;
}
```

This works great for protecting *www.example.com/analytics*. However, users are being prompted to login on each page, due to the fact that the Piwik tracking tag is on each page. In the [official FAQ](http://piwik.org/faq/troubleshooting/faq_58/), that problem is addressed for Apache, but not Nginx.

> If you use HTTP Authentication (Basic or Digest) on your Piwik files,
>   you should exclude piwik.php and piwik.js from this authentication, or
>   visitors on your website would be prompted with the authentication
>   popup.

What kind of Nginx rule can I use to protect all files in that directory, besides those two? Is it possible to do a negative regex match on a location block? I've seen solutions for Apache using *.htaccess*, but nothing for Nginx. Other similar questions are [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/23463146/4449419), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18383782/nginx-exclude-single-file-from-location), and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/9281564/4449419).

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
location = /analytics/piwik.php {
    fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;
    fastcgi_param /var/www/piwik/piwik.php;
}

location = /analytics/piwik.js {
    try_files $uri;
}
```

The `=` operator means that that these rules take first precedence. The problem with your current rules are that the `location /` rule is first in usage order. Using `=` changes that.

Comment: Do I need to remove the two location blocks I have above?

Comment: I kept the two locations blocks above and added yours. Here is what I have that **does** let me log in at _/analytics_, but **does not** stop the login prompt on each page.  
`location = /analytics/piwik.php {fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php5-fpm.sock;}`
`location = /analytics/piwik.js {try_files $uri piwik.js;}`
My error.log file is still showing this `no user/password was provided for basic authentication, client: XX.XX.XX.XX, server: example.com, request: "GET /analytics/piwik.js/ HTTP/1.1"...`

Comment: Asked on Nginx forum and answered [here](http://forum.nginx.org/read.php?2,256585,256630#msg-256630).